Angular 9 to angular 10 update (ERROR in Maximum call stack size exceeded)
I update my working angular application from v9 to v10, All packages are updated but when i run the through ng serve i got the below error:

I deleted the node_module folder and reinstall all the packages. also check lint but there is no circular dependencies.

Run again the migration and if the problem persists, read the changelog between these two versions and inspect your code to cover breaking changes or changes of behaviours
